# how to add javascript to the change_form.html for block content in django

Tags: python, django

I want to add a javascript to the model's change_form.html template inherited from the django admin's template. I would like to show/display some of the model's attributes based on the type of login. Eg. User can be a customer or staff group member. Can anyone guide? How to use it in the {% block content %} tag of the change_form.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `content` block, there is `head` block, you could place your js there. But that js thing that prevents some users from modifying some fields could be hacked easily.

```
{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            {% if user.get_profile.is_customer %}
                $('#id_of_field_block').hide();
            {% endif %}
        });
    </script>
{% endblock extrahead %}
```

Also you could change `change_form.html` template and override `content` block, getting original file content as source and change fieldset template `fieldset.html` (or you could override only fieldset.html, I'm not sure). This template iterates over fields and there you could add some checking.

Comment: Definitely we need to add the js in the extrahead block, but I want to show/hide some of the model attributes based on login. Let me try show () and hide() functions  with the div id